# Android Studio adding gradle repository gives "Invalid variable name. Must start with a letter"

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle, build

I am trying to add Charboost maven repository to my `build.gradle`. I am following their docs which say to do

```
repositories​ {
      maven​ { ​url​ ​"https://chartboostmobile.bintray.com/Chartboost"​ }
}
```

I already have and it works:

```
repositories {
  jcenter()
  google()
  flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
  }
}
```

But when I add `maven​ { ​url​ ​"https://chartboostmobile.bintray.com/Chartboost"​ }` I get

```
Could not compile build file '.../build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file '.../build.gradle': _: Invalid variable name. Must start with a letter but was: ​
  . At line _, column _.
         maven​ { ​url​ ​'https://chartboostmobile.bintray.com/Chartboost'​ }
                        ^
```

I've tried doing this with `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3` and `4.+` and I also tried `apply plugin: 'maven'` and `plugin { id 'maven' }`

Comment: Post your entire `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, that the syntax

```
maven​ { ​url​ ​"https://chartboostmobile.bintray.com/Chartboost"​ }
```

is for some reason not supported. I have fixed it by adding `()` around the url:

```
maven​ { ​url​(​"https://chartboostmobile.bintray.com/Chartboost"​) }
```